# How to catch the elements selected through both the conditions once page changes

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm trying to scrape some urls, but depending on the amount of results, the page code changes.
Both below are working, but none returns me 100% of the results. I'm trying to create a 'if' of some sort that will leave no NAN results.

```
url = [url.get_attribute("href") for url in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'base-card__full-link')))]
```

and

```
url = [url.get_attribute("href") for url in WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/section[2]/ul/li/a')))]
```

Would much appreciate your help.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of the *`href`* attributes you can clubup the conditions using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) within a *lambda* expression and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *lambda* expression:

  ```
  hrefs = [url.get_attribute("href") for url in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"base-card__full-link") or driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='main-content']/section[2]/ul/li/a"))]
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I totally understood what you did there, but it's not working. It's returning "'WebElement' object is not iterable" so it's not skipping the not found itens somehow.